# Is there a way to get Example data table inside @Before hooks in cucumber JAVA?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Each row in examples of a scenario outline are to be considered as a scenario. Hence, @Before hook will be called before each example. Before a scenario executes, can we get the example test data of that scenario and make some validations and prerequisite steps with the data. Tried many ways and searched a lot! Please suggest a way, if possible! Thanks in advance!

I tried using DataTable parameter at the @Before hook annotation. However, the signature of the @Before hook method does not allow using DataTable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: There is no way to do this.

The Before/After hooks don't have access to the example table, but you can tag your tests, so specific Before/After hooks get executed for specific tests.

Feature example:

```
@clearShoppingCart
  Scenario Outline:
    Login to the system..
    Add item to the shopping cart
    ....
```

Hooks example:

```
Before({tags: '@clearShoppingCart'}, function (scenario) {
    // clear the shopping cart logic or using API
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, Cucumber doesn't allow access to some of its internal classes as they are package private. I assume this is done to ensure we don't depend on internal implementation of Cucumber and the plugin is likely to work when upgrading.

However you can use ReflectionAPI to access the data from Scenario.

Feature file :

```
Feature: Book Store With Background
  Background: The Book Store
    Given I have the following books in the store
      | The Devil in the White City          | Erik Larson |
      | The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe | C.S. Lewis  |
      | In the Garden of Beasts              | Erik Larson |

  Scenario: Find books by author
    When I search for books by author Erik Larson
    Then I find 2 books
```

To extract datatable:

```
TestCaseState testCaseState = (TestCaseState)extractField(scenario,"delegate");
TestCase testCase = (TestCase)extractField(testCaseState,"testCase");
List<TestStep> testSteps = (List<TestStep>) extractField(testCase,"testSteps");
//since we are fetching data from first Given phrase
Step step = (Step)extractField(testSteps.get(0),"step");
DataTableArgument dataTableArgument = (DataTableArgument) step.getArgument();
final List<List<String>> cells = dataTableArgument.cells();
System.out.println("** Datatable Arguments **");
cells.stream().flatMap(a -> a.stream()).forEach(System.out::println);


private static <T> Object extractField(T t,String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = t.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(t);
}
```

Feel free to explore the complete source code of this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/krishnanunnijs/cucumber-example)